# Find a matrix or vector that solves the equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I wish to find an $\mathbf{F}$ that satisfies
$
\left[\begin{array}{r}
c_1^F\\
c_2^F\\
s_1^F\\
s_2^F
\end{array}\right]
=
\mathbf{F}
\left[\begin{array}{r}
c_1\\
c_2\\
s_1\\
s_2
\end{array}\right]
$

Some important facts are that $(c_1, c_2)$ and $(s_1, s_2)$ are coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^2$. $(c_1^F, c_2^F)$ and $(s_1^F, s_2^F)$ are $(c_1, c_2)$ and $(s_1, s_2)$ translated by $\overrightarrow{CS} =
\left[\begin{array}{r}
s_1-c_1\\
s_2-c_2
\end{array}\right]$.

How would you find $\mathbf{F}$? I have made an attempt and that is
$$
\mathbf{F} =
\left[\begin{array}{r}
s_1-c_1\\
s_2-c_2\\
s_1-c_1\\
s_2-c_2
\end{array}\right]
$$ but that is obviously wrong since they are multiplied and not added together :/.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{F}$ would need to be a matrix.

Using the translation, you can get one equation for each $c_1^F$, $c_2^F$, $s_1^F$ and $s_2^F$. For $(c_1^F, c_2^F)$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1^F \\
c_2^F
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
c_1 \\
c_2
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
s_1-c_1 \\
s_2-c_2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
s_1 \\
s_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

For $(s_1^F,s_2^F)$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
s_1^F \\
s_2^F
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
s_1 \\
s_2
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
s_1-c_1 \\
s_2-c_2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
2s_1-c_1 \\
2s_2-c_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Using the matrix equation, you get another equation for each $c_1^F$, $c_2^F$, $s_1^F$ and $s_2^F$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1^F \\
c_2^F \\
s_1^F \\
s_2^F
\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf{F}\begin{bmatrix}
c_1 \\
c_2 \\
s_1 \\
s_2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{F}_{11} & \mathbf{F}_{12} & \mathbf{F}_{13} & \mathbf{F}_{14} \\
\mathbf{F}_{21} & \mathbf{F}_{22} & \mathbf{F}_{23} & \mathbf{F}_{24} \\
\mathbf{F}_{31} & \mathbf{F}_{32} & \mathbf{F}_{33} & \mathbf{F}_{34} \\
\mathbf{F}_{41} & \mathbf{F}_{42} & \mathbf{F}_{43} & \mathbf{F}_{44}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
c_1 \\
c_2 \\
s_1 \\
s_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

You can then use the translation equations to fix the coefficients (matrix elements) of the matrix equation.

Take for instance $c_1^F$. You have two equations for it. The first comes from **F**, and amounts to $c_1^F=\mathbf{F}_{11}c_1+\mathbf{F}_{12}c_2+\mathbf{F}_{13}s_1+\mathbf{F}_{14}s_2$. The second comes from the translation, and amounts to $c_1^F=c_1+(s_1-c_1)=s_1$. For both of these equations to be satisfied regardless of the $c$'s and $s$'s, $\mathbf{F}_{13}=1$ and $\mathbf{F}_{11}=\mathbf{F}_{12}=\mathbf{F}_{14}=0$. Similarly, $c_2^F=\mathbf{F}_{21}c_1+\mathbf{F}_{22}c_2+\mathbf{F}_{23}s_1+\mathbf{F}_{24}s_2=c_2+(s_2-c_2)=s_2$ which means that $\mathbf{F}_{24}=1$ and $\mathbf{F}_{21}=\mathbf{F}_{22}=\mathbf{F}_{23}=0$.

$s_1^F$ and $s_2^F$ are a bit different, since $s_1^F=s_1+(s_1-c_1)=2s_1-c_1$ and $s_2^F=s_2+(s_2-c_2)=2s_2-c_2$. But similar analysis as above gives $\mathbf{F}_{31}=-1$, $\mathbf{F}_{33}=2$ and $\mathbf{F}_{32}=\mathbf{F}_{34}=0$ for $s_1^F$; and $\mathbf{F}_{42}=-1$, $\mathbf{F}_{44}=2$ and $\mathbf{F}_{41}=\mathbf{F}_{43}=0$.

Putting all this together,

$$
F=\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$